# Task scheduler running power shell script - Username error?

Tags: powershell, task, scheduler

So I have a powershell script that when a user logs into a PC it emails details of the login to me, for example username,IP,location etc. It runs from task scheduler and has a trigger on login.

The script runs fine through powershell my issue I am having that no matter who logs in it always runs the script on my account in task scheduler hence always inputting my name as the Username even tough a different user may be logged in. I've tried calling the username multiple ways but always shows my name as It runs off my account.

For calling the username I have used :

$username = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name

$env:UserName

$env:UserDomain

All return the user of who is running the scheduled task.

Any help to get it to print the true user who has logged in would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some code that you've tried?  You say you've tried multiple things already - it will be helpful to see what these are, and will avoid someone simply suggesting something you already know doesn't work.

Comment: Of course, for calling the user name what I have tried is - "$username = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name", "$env:UserName" and "$env:UserDomain". All return the user of who is running the scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because your scheduled task is executing with your credentials. There's no way around this, sadly. That said you can kind of side-step the behaviour by getting the user account associated with the explorer.exe process:

```
$username = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "Name='explorer.exe'" | ForEach-Object { $_.GetOwner() } | Select-Object -Unique -Expand User
```

This should work fine, as long as you aren't ever in a situation where multiple users could be logged into a machine at the same time (fast user switching, terminal services etc.)

EDIT: To get what you're after, you might need something more like this

```
$op = @()
$owners = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "Name='explorer.exe'" | ForEach-Object { $_.GetOwner() } | Select-Object -Unique -Expand User
foreach($owner in $owners)
{
    $wmiprocs = get-wmiobject win32_process -filter "Name='explorer.exe'" | where { $_.getowner().user -eq $owner } | select-object processid
    $procs = $wmiprocs | % { get-process -id $_.processid | select-object starttime }
    $obj = new-object object
    $obj | add-member -type noteproperty -name Username $owner
    $obj | add-member -type noteproperty -name Logon ($procs | sort -descending)[0].starttime
    $op += $obj
}

$op | ft -auto
```

Note that your PowerShell instance will need to be running as Admin to query the processes of other users.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Now it does seem to be skipping the task scheduler name but does list multiple users as they are logged in I believe. Is there anyway to break this into most recent or is that not possible? If not I may be able to use this by just displaying it in a different way.

Comment: Using that method, its not really possible. You might get better results monitoring the Security log for event id 4624 and extracting the data from the event. Again, you'll run into re-authentications and token refresh events etc. that will make it harder to pick out genuine logons.

Comment: Thinking about it, the WMI object has a ProcessId property which could also be captured and passed into Get-Process -Id cmdlet to give you access to that objects StartTime property which could then be ordered to retrieve the latest entry (most recently launched process)

Comment: Interesting, that may be something I will need to look into as I would like to have newest. Thanks for the help. Currently im getting System.Object[] as an output in the email I'm presuming because there is multiple coming back for IP etc as alot of people logged in.

Comment: @PaulA May have an answer for you - I've updated my code with an additional example.

Comment: Really appreciate your assistance in this. Ive ran that in a new script and looks great. Gonna try implement it now in current script and see how it does.